# NavigationView.ClearValue(NavigationView.MenuItemsProperty) always throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, winui-3

```cs
var temp = new NavigationView();
temp.ClearValue(NavigationView.MenuItemsProperty);

// System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
// Exception occurred: 'System.ArgumentException'(WinRT.Runtime.dll)
// WinRT Infomation: Argument 'source' is null.
```

The same result occurs even if temp.ReadLocalValue(NavigationView.MenuItemsProperty) does not return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

How can I have the same effect as calling ClearValue before calling SetBinding?

### Add

```
private record BindingInfo(FrameworkElement Target, DependencyProperty TargetDp, string Path);

private ImmutableDictionary<DependencyProperty, BindingInfo> _bindingInfos;

private void SetBindingIfValueIsSet(DependencyProperty sourceDp)
{
    if (ReadLocalValue(sourceDp) == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return;
    
    var (target, targetDp, path) = _bindingInfos[sourceDp];
    // target.ClearValue(targetDp);
    target.SetBinding(targetDp, new Binding
    {
        Source = this,
        Path = new(path),
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    });
}
```

In the above code, targetDp can be any Dp such as NavigationView.MenuItemsProperty and Panel.BackgroundProperty.

I use MenuItemsProperty instead of MenuItemsSourceProperty because I create NavigationViewItems in xaml.

Is it best to deal with unusual cases separately that cannot be handled with ClearValue?

Comment: Why do you want to call ``ClearValue`` on a new instance of ``NavigationView``?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding That is a shortened version of the question to simplify it. In fact, it applies to the instance of the NavigationView that is being displayed on the screen.

Comment: Does @Misha Zaslavsky's answer solve your issue? or do you need to do more than just clearing the current ``MenuItems``?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding There is no problem running the original code without calling ClearValue at this time, but I'm trying to call ClearValue before calling SetBinding, as [ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.bindingoperations?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3) says. I want to apply a consistent pattern because I use multiple DP's, but there is such an exception.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding I wrote the wrong link. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.data.bindingoperations.setbinding?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3#microsoft-ui-xaml-data-bindingoperations-setbinding(microsoft-ui-xaml-dependencyobject-microsoft-ui-xaml-dependencyproperty-microsoft-ui-xaml-data-bindingbase)) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`ClearValue` is not suitable for clearing the `MenuItems` collection of a `NavigationView` control because it is designed to clear the local value of a dependency property, not to manipulate the contents of a collection.

Try this instead:

```cs
var temp = new NavigationView();
temp.MenuItems.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch menu items source, you need to target `MenuItemsSourceProperty`, not `MenuItemsProperty`.

You also need to check if the property is null.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            Click="MenuItemsAButton_Click"
            Content="MenuItemsA" />
        <Button
            Click="MenuItemsBButton_Click"
            Content="MenuItemsB" />
    </StackPanel>
    <NavigationView
        x:Name="NavigationViewControl"
        Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MenuItemsA { get; set; } = new()
    {
        "Menu Item 1",
        "Menu Item 2",
        "Menu Item 3",
    };

    public ObservableCollection<string> MenuItemsB { get; set; } = new()
    {
        "Menu Item 4",
        "Menu Item 5",
        "Menu Item 6",
    };

    private void BindMenuItemsTo(string menuItemsPropertyName)
    {
        if (this.NavigationViewControl.MenuItemsSource is not null)
        {
            this.NavigationViewControl.ClearValue(NavigationView.MenuItemsSourceProperty);
        }

        this.NavigationViewControl.SetBinding(
            NavigationView.MenuItemsSourceProperty,
            new Binding()
            {
                Source = this,
                Path = new PropertyPath(menuItemsPropertyName),
            });
    }

    private void MenuItemsAButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindMenuItemsTo("MenuItemsA");
    }

    private void MenuItemsBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BindMenuItemsTo("MenuItemsB");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the content to my question.

Comment: Can you share more code around how your code works?

Comment: You can see all the codes [here](https://github.com/AppleTree1685/NewRepo), but the answer to my question would be best to deal with the exception case separately.

Comment: Since you can't bind to ``MenuItems`` in XAML,  I guess you are not supposed to call ``ClearValue`` on ``MenuItemsProperty``.